# Pandas Dataframe from dict with empty list value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read in a dictionary with two keys, the first with a string value and the second with a list of string values. The value containing a list can be (and often is) empty. For example:

`{'number': '50', 'box': []}`

However, when I try to use `DataFrame.from_dict`, it gives me an empty DataFrame. I notice that if the 'box' list has multiple elements, `DataFrame.from_dict` will give me a DataFrame with multiple rows, one for each value in the box list. This appears to be a sort of crossproduct behavior. Is there a way for me to suppress this behavior so that I can generate a DataFrame from the above example with one row, where the column "number" has value '50' and column "box" has value `[]`?

I am using Pandas 0.16.2 and Python 2.7.10 via Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit Windows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a DataFrame with a single row, you can provide a list with a single dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'number': '50', 'box': []}])
```

The [`from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) function expects a dict-of-lists, where the keys represent the columns and each value is a list (since DataFrame typically has more than one row) representing the values at each row. The following produces equivalent result using `from_dict`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'number': ['50'], 'box': [[]]})
```

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) doesn't show many options for this method.  Instead of an empty list you could pass it `[np.NaN]`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'number': '50', 'box': [np.NaN]})
```

which will return a dataframe with one row.